# Hide anchor tag according to if

Tags: html, spring, thymeleaf

I want to hide the content with in `<a></a>` , if `userTempory.recordStatus == == 'REJECTED'` , below you can see what is tried. but it's not working.

```
<td class="actions">
   <a class="btn-sm btn-default editBtn" th:if="${userTempory.recordStatus} == 'REJECTED' ? 'd-none' : ''"
      th:data-url="${userTempory.userName}"><i
          class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>Edit</a>
</td>
```

How to do this?

Comment: what is `d-none`? Is it class or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `th:classappend`

```
<td class="actions">
   <a class="btn-sm btn-default editBtn" th:classappend="${userTempory.recordStatus == 'REJECTED' ? 'd-none' : ''}" th:data-url="${userTempory.userName}"><i
       class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>Edit</a>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing you are using th:if in wrong manner. It ensures whether a element is shown conditionally or not. In your case you are trying to use it as a ternary operator.

just to help on that, please take a look at [this](http://itutorial.thymeleaf.org/exercise/8) link

I don't know what `d-none` is for? If I assume it's part of class value then following could be done to fix your code:

```
<td class="actions">
   <a class="btn-sm btn-default editBtn ${userTempory.recordStatus == 'REJECTED' ? 'd-none' : ''}"
      th:data-url="${userTempory.userName}"><i
          class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>Edit</a>
</td>
```

So, basically above uses Expression language of `thymleaf` to decide conditionally.